# Microsoft DI - Are objects referenced within a factory implementation disposed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, owin, .net-4.8, lifetime-scoping

Are objects that are **referenced, not created**, within a factory implementation disposed by the container? See code below:

```cs
services.AddTransient(c => OwinContext.ServiceObject);
```

Will `ServiceObject`, which implements `IDisposable`, be disposed by the container considering it isn't created (i.e. `new ServiceObject`)?

`ServiceObject` is currently registered as Scoped, but we are getting `ObjectDisposedException` on the rare occasion. I'm guessing it's getting disposed within OWIN sometimes before our services are able to use it, which is why I was hoping of making it Transient but I'm worried the container will dispose of it more frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposable transient registrations are **tracked by the container and disposed when their scope ends**.

The Microsoft documentation is not always clear about this, as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#services-not-created-by-the-service-container) documentation seems to suggest that "The framework does not dispose of the services automatically" that are "not created by the service container." Although the documentation is not incorrect, as it primarily talks about the registration of instances through the `AddSingleton<T>(T instance)` extension method — it is misleading because it doesn't hold for:

- `AddSingleton<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, T>)`,
- `AddScoped<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, T>)`, and
- `AddTransient<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, T>)`.

This statement can be easily verified using the following program:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var disposable = new FakeDisposable();

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddTransient(c => disposable);

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);

using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FakeDisposable>();
}

public class FakeDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
}
```

Output:

```
Disposed
```

**Conclusion:** Yes, transient registrations for disposable objects *are* disposed of by the container.

There will be little difference between making this registration Transient or Scoped. In both cases the object will get disposed when the scope ends.

In the case of a Transient registration, though, you'll start to see the disposable get disposed of multiple times in case it gets injected multiple times. For instance:

```cs
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FakeDisposable>();
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FakeDisposable>();
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<FakeDisposable>();
}
```

Output:

```
Disposed
Disposed
Disposed
```

From reliability, however, it's better to stick with a Scoped registration, instead of Transient. This is because MS.DI will prevent Scoped registrations from being injected into Singleton consumers (in case the Service Provider is created by calling `BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)`). In case your `ServiceContext` would get injected into a Singleton, it causes it to become a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) and keep referenced (and likely used) by that Singleton, long after it got disposed of.

The most likely reason you are getting those `ObjectDisposedException`s is because Owin tries to use the `ServiceContext` after your (web request) scope is disposed.

The `ServiceContext` object is likely being controlled and disposed of by OWIN, which doesn't make it a good candidate to be disposed of by the container. But here's the problem: MS.DI will *always* try to dispose of Transient and Scoped registrations and the only way to prevent this from happening is to *not* register your `ServiceContext`.

The solution, therefore, is to wrap it in a "provider" object of some sort. For instance:

```cs
// New abstraction
public interface IServiceObjectProvider
{
    object ServiceObject { get; }
}

// Implementation part of your Composition Root (see: https://mng.bz/K1qZ)
public class AmbientOwinServiceObjectProvider : IServiceObjectProvider
{
    public object ServiceObject => OwinContext.ServiceObject;
}

// Registration:
services.AddScoped<IServiceObjectProvider, AmbientOwinServiceObjectProvider>();

// Usage:
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceObjectProvider provider;

    public MyController(IServiceObjectProvider provider)
    {
        // Only store the dependency here: don't use it,
        // see: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        var so = this.provider.ServiceObject;
        // Do something with the Service object
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and confirming. Yeah thought about doing a wrapper, but was hesitant as it would incur refactoring many areas and a slight modification to rely on the wrapper's members. But that seems like a proper solution as opposed to changing the lifetime from scoped to transient.